# Why didn't the Kaminoans use the clones DNA?

Tags: star-wars

In one episode of the Clone Wars (I forget which) one of the Kaminoans say that due to Jango Fett's death, they had to use the only piece of DNA left and are using it to the point where it is starting to cause problems with the clones, but why don't they just take an older clone and use his DNA?

Comment: Biologically speaking, there is no reason why; a clone has identical DNA to its immediate ancestor. Also, the Kaminoans would have sequenced Jango's DNA at the very beginning of the cloning process, and so, they could have simply used that data for the cloning.

Comment: A copy of a copy:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRtVMLwh6mY

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CloneDegeneration

Comment: I seem to recall from Epsiode II that the DNA was altered to increase the growth rate and to make the clones more pliable. I don't know how plausible that is in biology but that was my recollection that could hand wave away using the clones' DNA instead of from the host.

Comment: The answer is contained in the episode you've mentioned. You can't clone a clone for ...erm ... reasons.